# text area border invisible is not happening

Tags: html, css

I want to make the text area border invisible. When the user clicks on the text area , I want to remove all the focus and and with no border.

My CSS

```
.message {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    margin : 0;
    resize: none;
}
```

I still see a thin line. How can i remove that. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/).I am using bootstrap 3

[image]

Comment: What browser ar you using? do you still see the border here? http://jsfiddle.net/Kj4uN/

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS. Better make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: your fiddle demo isn't pointing to right page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.message {
    border: 0 none #FFF;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-appearance:none !important;
}
```

This works !!!!

Answer (score 0):

It may be something else adding the border. Try adding

```
border: 0 !important;
```

If it works, you may want to find out what's causing it.

Comment: Did you try a different browsers?